# 3D tensors with tensorflow tf.matmul

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do a multiplication with two 3-D tensors, as defined:

```
a = tf.random_uniform(shape = [5,3,3])   

b = tf.ones(shape = [5,3,1])   

c = tf.matmul(a,b)
```

but I can't get the right answer as described in the tf.matmul function

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul

Comment: "but I can't get the right answer" - What is the actual issue? Is there an error message? Is there any output, etc?

Comment: This code is syntactically correct. It will perform a batch of five matrix multiplications by (effectively) unstacking `a` and `b` on the first dimension (into matrices of size 3x3 and 3x1), and then multiplying the respective pairs of matrices.

Comment: You're using `tf.random_uniform`. If you don't set a seed using `tf.set_random_seed` then you will get distinct results everytime you run your code. That's probably the reason you don't get "the right answer"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using Tensorflow r1.0?

In older versions, you would have needed to use [tf.batch_matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#batch_matmul) to multiply batches of matrices.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version, in r1.0, the tf.batch_matmul has enrolled in the function tf.matmul

Comment: I tried the code in your question using tf 1.0, and it works properly. the result c is of shape [5, 3, 1] as expected and the values are as expected. https://gist.github.com/yahiaetman/98936d503517ac90dabb9e978d58f91a